# Cover exposed insulation behind bathroom wall in basement

Tags: basement-insulation

I have a finished bathroom in the basement and 2 of the walls are shared by a storage room. On the storage room side, there is exposed insulation and pipes I’d like to cover.

What can I use to cover it?

I was looking at plastic sheeting or drywall or anything but with the moisture concerns I wasn’t sure.

[image: Exposed insulation with plumbing]

[image: exposed insulation with the back side of a shower surround]

Comment: What you put on the walls is influenced by Why you want to cover the walls.

Comment: I just want to hide the exposed insulation basically. Plastic, drywall, plywood, anything. Just unsure about the moisture concerns since the other side is a bathroom

Comment: Drywall will work fine.  There should be no moisture concerns as no moisture should go through the bathroom walls if they are done correctly.   No different than any other room in the house adjoining a bathroom.

Answer (score 1):

I would use plywood, which would make hanging various items easy. I would also mark the stud locations lightly on the floor and above and transfer those as vertical lines on the plywood, for the same reason.

Alternatively, you could use pegboard which would allow air movement and also facilitate using various wall hooks (although I personally am not a pegboard fan...)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking 1/4 plywood would be okay, pretty cheap. I was unsure about if it would trap moisture or not in the wall but probably okay. Elsewhere they covered the insulation with a thick plastic but not here

Comment: +1 for you since the OP didn't...

Answer (score 1):

Plywood would work well as would drywall. I don't think you'll have a problem with moisture. As long as the walls on the bathroom side are well sealed. You probably have greenboard on the bathroom side.
You also asked about covering the pipes. I did notice that your drain pipes come out past the studs instead of running through them. You'll probably want to furr those studs out possibly with 2x2s so you'll have an even surface to cover with your ply or drywall. After you furr it out and before you hang the wallboard you should protect the drains with a nail plate wherever they cross a stud.